# Bootstrap TouchSpin + NumeralJS using locale pt-br is not working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, numeral.js

I'm trying to use `bootstrap touchspin` + `numeraljs` to set the location of my currency input to `pt-br`.

For this I registered a custom locale through the `NumeralJS`, so when I use the locale that created the **increment** and **decrement** functions do not work correctly. If I use the locale `en`, the functions work perfectly.

The `javascript` code used is as follows:

```js
 (function(global, factory) {
   if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
     define(['../numeral'], factory);
   } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
     factory(require('../numeral'));
   } else {
     factory(global.numeral);
   }
 }(this, function(numeral) {
   numeral.register('locale', 'pt-br', {
     delimiters: {
       thousands: '.',
       decimal: ','
     },
     abbreviations: {
       thousand: 'mil',
       million: 'milhões',
       billion: 'b',
       trillion: 't'
     },
     ordinal: function(number) {
       return 'º';
     },
     currency: {
       symbol: 'R$'
     }
   });
 }));


 numeral.locale('pt-br');
 $("input[name='demo_callback']").TouchSpin({
   callback_before_calculation: function(v) {

     return numeral(v).value();
   },
   callback_after_calculation: function(v) {

     return numeral(v).format("$0,0.00");
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-touchspin/4.2.5/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>


<input id="demo_callback" type="text" value="1.00" data-bts-min="-1" data-bts-max="1000000" data-bts-step=".01" data-bts-decimals="2" name="demo_callback" />
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all who tried to help,

I was able to solve the problem by replacing the **decimal separator** of the locale `en` with the decimal separator of the locale `pt-br` before sending it to the conversion via `NumeralJS`:

```js
 (function(global, factory) {
   if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
     define(['../numeral'], factory);
   } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
     factory(require('../numeral'));
   } else {
     factory(global.numeral);
   }
 }(this, function(numeral) {
   numeral.register('locale', 'pt-br', {
     delimiters: {
       thousands: '.',
       decimal: ','
     },
     abbreviations: {
       thousand: 'mil',
       million: 'milhões',
       billion: 'b',
       trillion: 't'
     },
     ordinal: function(number) {
       return 'º';
     },
     currency: {
       symbol: 'R$'
     }
   });
 }));


 numeral.locale('pt-br');
 $("input[name='demo_callback']").TouchSpin({
   callback_before_calculation: function(v) {

     return numeral(v.replace('.', ',')).value();
   },
   callback_after_calculation: function(v) {

     return numeral(v.replace('.', ',')).format("$0,0.00");
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-touchspin/4.2.5/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>


<input id="demo_callback" type="text" value="1.00" data-bts-min="-1" data-bts-max="1000000" data-bts-step=".01" data-bts-decimals="2" name="demo_callback" />
```